# Why declared field in data with props initial value is undefined?

Tags: vue.js, mutation, prop

Since mutating a prop is an antipattern I do the following as one of the solutions to that, however when I console.log my new data field I get undefined. What's wrong?

```vue
export default {
 name: "modal",
 props: ["show"],
 data() {
  return {
    sent: false,
    mutableShow: this.show
  };
},
methods: {
  closeModal: function() {
    this.mutableShow = false;
  },
  sendTeam: function() {
    var self = this;
    let clientId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("projectClient")).id;
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: "/send-project-team/" + clientId,
      data: data
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      self.sent = true;
      $("h3").text("Wooo");
      $(".modal-body").text("Team was sent succesfully to client");
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(this.mutableShow);
        self.closeModal();
      }, 3000);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
 }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your timeout handler is establishing a new context. Instead of

```
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(this.mutableShow);
    self.closeModal();
}, 3000);
```

you could use

```
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(this.mutableShow);
    self.closeModal();
}, 3000);
```

And you'd need to make a similar change to

```
.then(function(response) {
```

to

```
.then(response => {
```

having said that, though, I'm not sure the code is going to behave as you might want it. Once the users closes the modal, it won't be possible to open it again since there is no way to make `mutableShow` equal to `true`.

**Edited to add:**

Since you're defining the `self` variable, you could also use that.

```
console.log(self.mutableShow);
```

**Edited to add:**

Without knowing specifically what behavior is intended, the best suggestion I can offer is to follow accepted Vue practices. Namely, after the AJAX request succeeds, emit a custom event. Have the parent component listen for that event and, when triggered, change the `show` prop.

Comment: I have tried your solution and it works with self, but you are right it does not behave as expected. Do you have an idea on how to make it as it should behave?